# What is the best way to share some data across several view controllers in the iOS application

Tags: ios, architecture, singleton

I need to share some data (such as user ID, current password, etc) across several view controllers in the iOS application while its working (of course, for offline password storage I will use keychain). What is the best way to share it in this case? Should I create some singleton object like `UserInfo` and access its properties from all parts of the application or not? Is it ok to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the credentials and such are not found in any backend, I would just store them inside `NSUserDefaults` and set those values to properties in a singleton class. If you were using a backend like Parse, then you could just use their built in functionality for stuff like this (i.e. PFUser).

Some people like to store this stuff inside the `AppDelegate`, but I would not do so. I have a blog post explaining why not to [here.](http://bit.ly/3mistakesios)

Additionally, you can always pass data back and forth using the segues, particuarly inside `prepareForSegue`. Sometimes it makes sense, and sometimes it doesn't because those members are going to have to be public and exposed. That would look like this:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"SEGUE_ID"])
    {
        DestinationViewController *dvc = [segue destinationViewController];

        // Pass any objects to the view controller here, like...
        dvc.someMember = whatever
    }
}
```

Comment: There are so many view controllers around here, so I don't want to use plain setters and segues in this case. btw, I thought that `NSUserDefaults` will be saved on the disk, am I right? If so, I don't want password to be stored on the disk, only in the memory while application is running

Comment: If you want a local cache then you *could* store a collection inside the AppDelegate. That'll get nuked between launches.

Comment: And what's wrong with the separate singleton object?

Comment: @FrozenHeart not a thing, I don't know how the credentials are manifested but from your description, I'd say that is your best option. Just get a reference to that inside your VCs and you are good to go.